# Inactive posts for the last six months

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, data-explorer

I wonder how to find all the inactive for at least 6 months posts in mathstack? Thanks.

Comment: Please avoid gaming the system too much.

Comment: This is an advise or joke?): @Asaf karagila

Comment: Consider it a directive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

StackExchange Data Explorer is your friend!

https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/779357/excavator-badge

(I am guessing this is the search you want....)